# Use Arabic numbers in Telerik Controls - Win Forms

Tags: c#, telerik

I have added a Telerik radio button into my form. Its text contains numbers. I need to use Arabic numbers. How can I use  Arabic numbers in Telerik controls?

Comment: this might help http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports.html
this too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(VS.95).aspx